# Why is this `dd` command producing `Resource busy` errors?

Tags: osx, hard-disk, dd, usb-drive, resources

I'm attempting to recover anything possible from a known-bad hard disk (failing, or failed). I began with `dd` and realized I didn't unmount. After unmounting volumes, I was able to correctly begin the disk duplication...

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/rdisk3 of=/dev/rdisk2 bs=1m conv=noerror,sync
Password:
dd: /dev/rdisk2: Resource busy
[user@host:~|14:14:27]
$ diskutil umountDisk /dev/rdisk2
Unmount of all volumes on disk2 was successful
[user@host:~|14:14:42]
$ sudo dd if=/dev/rdisk3 of=/dev/rdisk2 bs=1m conv=noerror,sync
dd: /dev/rdisk3: Input/output error
166427+0 records in
166427+0 records out
174511357952 bytes transferred in 3547.896249 secs (49187278 bytes/sec)
dd: /dev/rdisk3: Input/output error
dd: /dev/rdisk3: Resource busy
166428+0 records in
166428+0 records out
...<snip>...
```

... as I expect, I see `Input/output error` messages. But I also see `Resource busy`. Why is that?

I suspected the hard drives might be going to sleep (copy attempt is taking many hours), but I checked, and the system is set to not sleep hard drives.

Here's another output sample...

```
...<snip>...
231213105152 bytes transferred in 202223.059877 secs (1143357 bytes/sec)
dd: /dev/rdisk3: Resource busy
dd: /dev/rdisk3: Resource busy
220503+0 records in
220503+0 records out
231214153728 bytes transferred in 202254.074286 secs (1143187 bytes/sec)
dd: /dev/rdisk3: Resource busy
dd: /dev/rdisk3: Input/output error
220504+0 records in
220504+0 records out
...<snip>...
```

What is causing this `Input/output error` message, and can I solve it in hopes of recovering this data?

Comment: Guess: Tagged SCSI, which means several SCSI commands in flight, and one of those additional SCSI commands return with "resource busy" because the other SCSI commands have run into the I/O error (which keeps the resource, namely the harddisk, busy). Have a look at `dmesg`, and you may see error messages that confirm the guess.